# How to use if to filter in a map function in scala?

Tags: scala, collections, apache-spark, flatmap

I've got a hadoopFiles object which is generated from `sc.newAPIHadoopFile`.

```
scala> hadoopFiles
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)] = UnionRDD[64] at union at <console>:24
```

I intend to iterate through all the lines in hadoopFiles with operation and filter on it, In which, a `if` check is applied and will throw an exception:

```
scala> val rowRDD = hadoopFiles.map(line =>
     |           line._2.toString.split("\\^") map {
     |             field => {
     |               var pair = field.split("=", 2)
     |               if(pair.length == 2)
     |                 (pair(0) -> pair(1))
     |             }
     |           } toMap
     |         ).map(kvs => Row(kvs("uuid"), kvs("ip"), kvs("plt").trim))
<console>:33: error: Cannot prove that Any <:< (T, U).
                 } toMap
                   ^
```

However, if I remove the `if(pair.length == 2)` part, it will works fine:

```
scala>     val rowRDD = hadoopFiles.map(line =>
     |           line._2.toString.split("\\^") map {
     |             field => {
     |               var pair = field.split("=", 2)
     |               (pair(0) -> pair(1))
     |             }
     |           } toMap
     |         ).map(kvs => Row(kvs("uuid"), kvs("ip"), kvs("plt").trim))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Row] = MappedRDD[66] at map at <console>:33
```

Could anyone tell me the reason for this phenomenon, and show me the correct way to apply the `if` statement. Thanks a lot!

**P.S.** We could use this simplified example to test:

```
"1=a^2=b^3".split("\\^") map {
            field => {
              var pair = field.split("=", 2)
              if(pair.length == 2)
                pair(0) -> pair(1)
              else
                return
            }
          } toMap
```

Comment: What if `pair.length != 2`. You have provide something for that case too.

Comment: Just filter it out.  I only look for key-value pairs which is exactly composed of 2 parts. @SarveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect`:

```
val res = "1=a^2=b^3".split("\\^") collect {
  _.split("=", 2) match {
    case Array(a, b) => a -> b
  }
} toMap

println(res) // Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)
```

In your particular case the following happens:

```
case class Row(uuid: String, ip: String, plt: String)
val hadoopFiles = List(("", "uuid=a^ip=b^plt"))

val rowRDD = hadoopFiles.map(line =>
  line._2.toString.split("\\^") map {
    field =>
      {
        var pair = field.split("=", 2)
        val res = if (pair.length == 2)
          (pair(0) -> pair(1))
        res  // res: Any (common super class for (String, String)
             // which is Tuple2 and Unit (result for case when 
             // pair.length != 2)
      }
  } /* <<< returns Array[Any] */ /*toMap*/ ) 
  //.map(kvs => Row(kvs("uuid"), kvs("ip"), kvs("plt").trim))
```

The result of inner map is `Any` and map yields Array[Any]. If you look at `toMap` definition you will see:

```
  def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U] = {
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[T, U]
    for (x <- self)
      b += x // <<< implicit conversion from each `x` of class `A` in `self`
             // to (T, U) because we have `implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)`
    b.result()
  }
```

For your `Array[Any]` there is no implicit conversion from `Any` to `(T, U)` in current context. Because of this your code fails.
If you add else alternative:

```
  val rowRDD = hadoopFiles.map(line =>
    (line._2.toString.split("\\^") map {
      field =>
        {
          var pair = field.split("=", 2)
          val res = if (pair.length == 2)
            (pair(0) -> pair(1))
          else ("" -> "") // dummy, just for demo
          res // res: (String, String)
        }
    } toMap) withDefaultValue ("") 
           /*withDefaultValue just to avoid Exception for this demo*/ )
    .map(kvs => Row(kvs("uuid"), kvs("ip"), kvs("plt").trim))

  println(rowRDD) // List(Row(a,b,))
```

Here your result will be Array[(String, String)] and there is an implicit conversion from `(String, String)` to `(T, U)`. So the code compiles and works.

Answer (score 3):

To map over a collection and only keep some of the mapped elements, you can use `flatMap`. `flatMap` takes a function that returns a collection, e.g. instance an `Option`. Now the `if` expression needs to have an `else` part that returns an empty `Option`, i.e. `None`.

```
scala> val rowRDD = hadoopFiles.map(line =>
     |           line._2.toString.split("\\^") flatMap {
     |             field => {
     |               var pair = field.split("=", 2)
     |               if (pair.length == 2)
     |                 Some(pair(0) -> pair(1))
     |               else
     |                 None
     |             }
     |           } toMap
     |         ).map(kvs => Row(kvs("uuid"), kvs("ip"), kvs("plt").trim))
```

Comment: That is to say, if my line looks like '1=a^2=b^3', the above flatMap function will just return (1->a) and (2->b) ? I'm new to scala as well as Spark, what does the `Some` and `None` keyword serves here interacting with `flatMap`? Why not the `map` function?

Comment: Well, it throws another error: **error: value flatmap is not a member of Array[String]**

Comment: `Some` and `None` aren't keywords. They are subclasses of `Option`, which is a container that can have zero elements(`None`) or one element (`Some`).

Comment: When revising to `flatMap`, it is just what I expected. Thanks for your detailed explanation :]